# When using Magento 2 the admin panel buttons are un-responsive

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

After changing the password and language the admin panel buttons no longer worked (were un-responsive). In trying to fix this issue I did the following,

1. Removed the pub/static folder
2. Ran php bin/magento cache:clean and php bin/magento cache:flush
3. Next I ran php bin/magento setup:di::compile then php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

After doing this the style for the site has gone and the links still no longer work. What can I do to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to give proper permission to the folders, run following from magento 2 root;

```
chmod 777 -R var pub generated
```

You can omit generated folder if you're still on 2.1.x or 2.0.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run below command:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend en_US
```

Comment: Sorry to say none of the suggestions have worked